# Migrate to Spring Batch 5 - BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table is corrupted

Tags: mysql, spring-batch

I am following the steps to upgrade Spring Batch from 4 to 5:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#column-change-in-batch_step_execution

I am running the migration query for the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table:

`ALTER TABLE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION ADD CREATE_TIME DATETIME(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00';`

But it turns out that the table is corrupted somehow as I am getting this error from MySql:

`ERROR 1033 (HY000): Incorrect information in file: './generic_payment_plans/batch_step_execution.frm'`

I asked a friend to do the same migration herself - we both use the `amd64/mysql:5.7` MySql docker image. She experiences the same error.
I also tried to remove the database and recreate it, then to run the query - same error.

Any ideas?